# how to get rid of security message box from gecko webbrowser

Tags: c#, firefox, messagebox, gecko, security-warning

I'm using gecko `webbrowser` control in my `winforms` app, it's belonging to firefox browser.

When I navigate to `www.facebook.com` I get this messagebox immediately :

[image: Security Warning that I get]

it's really annoying , I tried to press enter by code when my webbrowser loses focus but it doesn't work.. how to get rid of it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Application.OpenForms[1].Close();
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? Is `OpenForms[1]` always the correct choice?

Comment: At first I thought that message box is not a form ,but when I checked Application.OpenForms.count it was 2 , so I closed it as above. I was searching for an answer , I don't know when it is correct and when it is not,I discovered this accidentally :D